# How to implement ViewPagerIndicator both title and circle

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-custom-view, viewpagerindicator

How to implement ViewPagerIndicator like [SwiftPagingNav iOS Library](https://github.com/aubrey/SwiftPagingNav)

- Show only title of current page
- When swipe show both current and next or previous page

Now I can show both title indicator and circle indicator but now it show 2 or 3 title of page, I want only current page and prev or next when swipe

**[images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrAwZ.png)**

Sorry for bad english

Comment: Use https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator

Comment: Follow the answer given..!

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to set View Pager Indicator as you needed :

```
 /*
* Function to set Indicator to ViewPager.
* */
public void setIndicator() {
    yourViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.yourViewPager);
    yourAdapter adpt = new yourAdapter(YourActivity.this);
    yourViewPager.setAdapter(adpt);
    count_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.image_count);
    count = yourArrayList.size();
    page_text = new ImageView[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        page_text[i] = new ImageView(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.setMargins(5, 0, 5, 0);
        page_text[i].setLayoutParams(lp);
        page_text[i].setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pagination_default));
        count_layout.addView(page_text[i]);
    }
    yourViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    page_text[i]
                            .setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pagination_default));
                }

                page_text[position]
                        .setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pagination_selected));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    });
}
```

As from code logic, You can see that I have created Array for the total images i.e. `page_text[]`

Your layout might be like as below :

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relContent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/yourViewPager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/image_count"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linTemp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/viewPagerItemDetails"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollTags"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```